# Would you please tell me if it was said vs. it said are the same?

Tags: passive-voice

> In the book **it said**: "The Boa swallows its prey".
>
> In the book **it was said** :" The Boa swallows its prey".

Would you tell me if these are correct? And is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

The first is more correct. This is still very passive. I would use:

The book said "The Boa swallows its prey."

"it was said" implies a rumor or a common belief.

Jennifer, it was said, spent money easily.

Comment: Thanks. But, I cannot get all that you have already explained.